# Determine if any complex numbers exist in a matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, matrix, nested-for-loop

I am writing a function to determine if the elements of a matrix are complex. I expect the function to either return a `True` or a `False`. I have this code but it seems not working as expected:

```
def confirm_matrix(M):
    row_1_length = len(M[0])
    if len(M)>0:
        for row in M:
            if type(row) is not list or tuple:
                return False
            for row in M[1:]:
                if len(row)!= row_1_length:
                    return False
                for row in M:
                    for element in row:
                        try:
                            isinstance(element, complex) == True
                            return True
                        except:
                            return False
confirm_matrix([[1j,1j],[2j,2j]])
```

I expect to get a `True` but this gives `False`. What can I make better in my code here?

Comment: Consider using [`numpy.iscomplex()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.iscomplex.html) for speed

Answer (score 5):

The logic here is overkill. If your matrix is always 2d, you can iterate the rows and columns and pass the generator to `any`:

```
>>> M = [[1j,1j],[2j,2j]]
>>> any(isinstance(x, complex) for row in M for x in row)
True
>>> M = [[1,1],[2,2]]
>>> any(isinstance(x, complex) for row in M for x in row)
False
```

If you're using numpy, [`np.iscomplex()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.iscomplex.html) is the way to go:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1+1j, 1+0j], [4.5, 3]])
>>> np.iscomplex(a).any()
True
```